# Why wont my the_date show the short version of the month?

Tags: wordpress

When I try to use the short version of months like "Jan", "Feb" I'm supposed to use M as a syntax in the the_time(). But when I do, there is nothing showing. At all. When i use the the whole month name with 'F', it shows as normal.

```
<?php the_date('M') ?>
```

Have earlier been into the files and translated the dates, but don't remember what file I was editing. Might be the file I edited that have been messed up.

Any help?

Comment: Have you tried with `get_the_date()`

Comment: Yes. Have tried most of the attributes

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalled the locate.php file and everything worked.